# Storing a vector of various void function pointers with its parameters

Tags: c++, function, vector, function-pointers

I'm looking for a way to store function pointers in a container like a vector. This is possible if all the functions have the same parameters but can I do if the functions have individually unique parameters?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void sayHi() {
    cout << "Hi" << endl;
}

void sayNum(int num) {
    cout << num << endl;
}

int main() {
    vector<void(*)()> funcs; // vector of 0 argument functions
    funcs.push_back(sayHi);
    funcs.push_back(sayNum); // can't store sayNum because it takes arguments
}
```

Note that I can't use std::function or std::bind because VS2013 doesn't have them and I'd rather not use the boost library. The solution must be allow the possibility to iterate through the vector of function pointers and execute each one with some valid arguments.

Forgive my potential ignorance about how function pointers work, I'm very used to doing this sort of thing in Javascript in one statement :P

Comment: And how would you use this thing?

Comment: So a valid answer would be a minimalistic `function` implementation?

Comment: VS2013 has both `std::function` and `std::bind`.

Comment: @Columbo How would you use even `std::function` with different parameters? AFAIK, each `std::function` has a different type, so you'd need some kind of `boost::any` approach.

Comment: @vsoftco Erm, yeah. `any`, mea culpa.

Comment: All the functions would be void type. The parameters would be only matched to their functions. i.e. storing a vector of functions with their given arguments so they can be executed at a later time.

Comment: @Jazcash Still don't understand how would you have a `std::vector` with functions returning e.g. `void` but each taking different parameters (types/numbers)? What do you mean by "functions have individually unique parameters"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2103 has `std::function`, `std::bind` and lambdas.  Simply use them.

Comment: Completely my bad, I wasn't including <functional>. Just a rookie mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Made the mistake of not including  as I couldn't see it mentioned in anybody's code examples but it's probably just me being bad at C++.

Not going to accept my own answer, but thought I'd post my code just in the interests of anybody who might find it useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> f_list;
f_list f1;

void _sayHi();
void _sayNum(int num);

void sayHi() {
    f1.push_back(
        std::bind(&_sayHi)
    );
}

void sayNum(int num) {
    f1.push_back(
        std::bind(&_sayNum, num)
    );
}

void _sayHi() {
    cout << "hi" << endl;
}
void _sayNum(int num) {
    cout << num << endl;
}

int main() {
    sayHi();
    sayNum(5);

    for (int i = 0; i < f1.size(); i++) {
        f1.at(i)();  // will execute desired functions
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you use `std::bind` on `_sayHi`? It already has the correct signature, you can just add it directly to the vector.